# wordpress custom fields meta query : find given key value or any values

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I'm trying to get posts with a meta query from a form made of select (drop down menu). Everything works well, except when I select the first option on both selects (where option value is marked "*" in my example). I naively tried option value * or All, but nothing works.

These first choices have to get all posts (from a particular category) whatever the key values they have (even they don't have one). It has to basically ignore any key values.

This is my form :

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter">


            <label for="inhalation">Inhalation :</label>
                <select name="inhalation" id="inhalation">
                        <option value="*">Any value</option>
                        <option value="Directe">Directe</option>
                        <option value="Indirecte">Indirecte</option>
                        <option value="Directe / Indirecte">Directe / Indirecte</option>
                </select>

             <label for="inhalation">Profil :</label>
                <select name="profil" id="profil">
                        <option value="*">Any value</option>
                        <option value="Débutant">Débutant</option>
                        <option value="Avancé">Avancé</option>
                        <option value="Débutant / Avancé">Débutant / avancé</option>
                        <option value="Expert">Expert</option>
                </select>


        <button>Filtrer les revues</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="myfilter">
        <input type="hidden" name="current-cat" value="<?php echo esc_html( $postcat[0]->term_id ); ?>">

    </form>
```

And this is my php query (form data is sent via Jquery) :

```
function my_filter_function(){
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'cat' => $_POST['current-cat'],
    'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'Inhalation',
        'value' => $_POST['inhalation']
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'Profil',
        'value' => $_POST['profil']
    ))
);


$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

As you may have noticed I'm not a coder. Sorry in advance if the question might look stupid. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the default value to `all` or something similar that relates to an all types value. Next up, create the query argument and add it to the meta query if the user is not looking for all types. That way it'll get added to the meta query to explicitly search for if necessary as you can assume `all` accounts for everything in the database.

```php
function my_filter_function() {

    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'cat' => $_POST['current-cat'],
        'meta_query' => array()
    );

    if ( 'all' != $_POST['inhalation'] ) {

        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'Inhalation',
            'value' => $_POST['inhalation']
        );

    }

    if ( 'all' != $_POST['profil'] ) {

        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'Profil',
            'value' => $_POST['profil']
        );

    }

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

}
```